# image tag does not load images with absolute path given Wordpress plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, absolute-path

i have a very strange problem and never faced it before, its not problem with the plugin which i have installed but i don't know why image tag doesn't load few images although images are available on the url if you type same url in browser you will see image but i won't load in the image tag kindly check the screenshot RSS link is displaying image properly on website but FACEBOOK and TWITTER don't show images but if you copy same linke from TWITER or FACEBOOK in url than you can see the image.

[image]

Regards

Comment: Have a look in the browser console. Are the requests being blocked, because they are not secure and because of facebook's http headers? (http vs https)

Comment: It is strongly recommended to include code-samples as text not as image: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: ohhh sorry i got the solution actually in my addblock i have selected not to show social media links when i disable the addblocker everything works fine